# Loop does not return all data JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, html

I have 2 nested loops, the first one to get the state, and the second one to get the state's cites. But the loops don't return all states or cities , just return some of them. Here is my html5 and JavaScript code

```
<html >
<head >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cities</title>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
<nav class="current">
<button class='back' >Navigation</button>
<h1>States</h1>
</nav>  
<article id="main" class="current">
<section>
  <ul class='list' role='list'>
    <li class='comp' data-goto="Cairo">
      <div>
        <h3>Cairo</h3>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <span class='nav'></span>
      </aside>
    </li>
</ul>
</section>
</article>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var City={"Cairo":
[{"id":1,"name":"القاهرة","gov":"القاهرة","gov_id":"1"},{"id":8,"name":"الرحاب","gov":"القاهرة","gov_id":"1"},{"id":10,"name":"القاهرة الجديدة","gov":"القاهرة","gov_id":"1"},{"id":23,"name":"الشروق","gov":"القاهرة","gov_id":"1"},{"id":34,"name":"مدينة السلام","gov":"القاهرة","gov_id":"1"}], 
"Giza":[{"id":2,"name":"الجيزة","gov":"الجيزة","gov_id":"2"},{"id":9,"name":"الشيخ زايد","gov":"الجيزة","gov_id":"2"},{"id":13,"name":"6 أكتوبر","gov":"الجيزة","gov_id":"2"}],
"Alexandria":[{"id":3,"name":"الاسكندرية","gov":"الاسكندرية","gov_id":"3"}],
"Ismaïlia":[{"id":4,"name":"الاسماعيلية","gov":"الاسماعيلية","gov_id":"4"}],
"Aswan":[{"id":5,"name":"اسوان","gov":"اسوان","gov_id":"5"}],
"Asuit":[{"id":6,"name":"اسيوط","gov":"اسيوط","gov_id":"6"}],
"Luxor":[{"id":7,"name":"الاقصر","gov":"الاقصر","gov_id":"7"},{"id":31,"name":"أدفو","gov":"الاقصر","gov_id":"7"}],
"Red-Sea":[{"id":29,"name":"الغردقة","gov":"البحر الاحمر","gov_id":"8"}],
"Beheira ":[{"id":11,"name":"رشيد","gov":"البحيرة","gov_id":"9"},{"id":16,"name":"دمنهور","gov":"البحيرة","gov_id":"9"}]};

     var mdata=""; 
Object.keys(City).forEach(function(value, key) {
        mdata=mdata+"<article id='" + value + "' class='next'>";
        mdata=mdata+"<section>";
        mdata=mdata+"<ul id='blog-list' class='list'>";

         City[value].forEach(function(v, k) {

         mdata=mdata+"<li class='comp' data-goto='detail'>"+
                    "<table style='width: 100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>"+
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td style='width:12%'><img src='images/vets/cat-icon.png' style='width:70%;height:60%' valign='middle'></td>"+
                    "<td style='font-size:large;' valign='top'><h3>" + v.name +
                    "</h3></td></tr></table></li><aside><span class='nav'></span></aside>";                                     
        })                  
        });
        mdata=mdata+"</ul>";
        mdata=mdata+"</section>";
        mdata=mdata+"</article>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML= mdata;
         </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a lot of `article`, `section`, and `ul` start tags, and then only closing them once.

Move your ending of the first `forEach` loop to just after your closing `article` tag and just before setting your `innerHTML`.